# Turning 360 video into touchable object

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, 360-degrees

I have this 360 video of an object and I want to make it touchable so the user will be able to touch and turn it from one side to another, the video length is just 10 seconds from one side to another.

Maybe if I will have another format if images or another kind of video it could be better?  I want the user to be able to turn it around, right and left, up and down and to zoom in and out.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found a better solution that doing it with video. I took all the video frames and save them as png files, than loaded them into array and used it instead of video.